# Subnet mask -Issue-Static IP

Tags: wireless-networking, lan

What is the mean if subnet mask is same for two static ip's ?

Ex:- subnet mask - 255.255.255.252 - this same for two static ips- that i purchased from ISP.

Answer (score 2):

It just means their networks have the same number of possible hosts. The subnet mask alone doesn't tell you what subnet an IP is on. `255.255.255.252` only has two bits clear (252 is `11111100` in binary), so that network has a maximum of 2 hosts (`2^2` is 4, but 2 host spots are always taken by the network address and broadcast address).

If you want to check whether two IPs with the same subnet mask are on the same network, binary `AND` each with the subnet mask and see if you get the same thing. `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.2` are on the same subnet (because `AND` either of them with `255.255.255.252` is `192.168.0.0`, their network address). However, `192.168.0.9` isn't on that subnet, because `AND`ing that with the subnet mask produces `192.168.0.8`.

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that the size of the "subnet" is the same.

The "subnet mask" is a way of specifying the size of the subnet.  That means it is a way of specifying how many network addresses are in the subnet.

A subnet using the IPv4 "subnet mask" of 255.255.255.252 is often called a "point to point" subnet, because there are only four IPv4 addresses.  The first address is often called "unusable" because it is reserved as a "Network ID" (and was used as a "broadcast address" on some older equipment).  The last address of those four is the modern standard for the IPv4 "broadcast address".  The middle two addresses are available for use by a computer or other device.  Because there are only two addresses available, this the network connection is presumed to be treated like a "point to point" link.

If you want to see how many addresses are available for a subnet mask, you may check out a Variable Length Subnet Mask (VLSM) chart, which will show this visually.